# The method is not called inside a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't access `read_file()` method inside an instance class in Python 3.7.
I want to print the `list` list_values_end`with functions`print_file()`.  When calling the function` print_file ()`the terminal produces`<__ main __. ReadFile object at 0x0082EA70>` instead of
the expected list. Please explain what was done wrong? The code is attached.

```
class ReadFile():
"""Чтение из файла"""
def __init__(self):
    
    self.file_r = 'val_kWt.txt'
    self.read_file(self.file_r)
                    
    self.print_file(self)

def read_file(self, file_r):
    list_values_end = []
    vk = open(file_r, 'r')
    list_values = vk.readlines()

    for list_value in list_values:
        list_values_end.append(list_value.rstrip())
    
    vk.close()
    print(list_values_end)
     
    return list_values_end
    
def print_file(self, list_values_end):
    print(list_values_end)
```

examp = ReadFile()

Comment: `read_file` will never execute `print(list_values_end)` since you `return` a value on the previous line.

Comment: You should not have anything after a `return` statement. Anything after that keyword will be ingonred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place `print` before `return` statement.
Try this instead:

```
class ReadFile():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.file_r = 'val_kWt.txt'
        self.read_file(self.file_r)
        
        self.a = 12
        self.print_a(self.a)
        
    def print_a(self, a):
        print('Printing ', a)

    def read_file(self, file_r):
        list_values_end = []
        vk = open(file_r, 'r')
        list_values = vk.readlines()
 
        for list_value in list_values:
            list_values_end.append(list_value.rstrip())
        
        vk.close()
        print(list_values_end)
        return list_values_end
```

**Edited according to question modification**

You passed the object to `print_file` function. Instead you should have passed the return value of read_file

```
class ReadFile():
    """Чтение из файла"""
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.file_r = 'val_kWt.txt'
        list_value_end = self.read_file(self.file_r)
                        
        self.print_file(list_value_end)
    
    def read_file(self, file_r):
        list_values_end = []
        vk = open(file_r, 'r')
        list_values = vk.readlines()
 
        for list_value in list_values:
            list_values_end.append(list_value.rstrip())
        
        vk.close()
        print(list_values_end)
         
        return list_values_end
        
    def print_file(self, list_values_end):
        print(list_values_end)

examp = ReadFile()
```